# how to create different settings for each UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview with multiple sections.

I want to make some of them selectable, and others not. Also, the cells that are selectable should link to different ViewControllers.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In another question of mine, somebody gave an answer that is also applicable for this.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, you can just set if-statements to access every cell in every section individually:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            //do any cell setup
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            //do any cell setup
        }
   }
if (indexPath.section == 1) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                //do any cell setup
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                //do any cell setup
            }
       }
```

and so on. this allows you to fill the cel with anything, but also to do all the setup you want for every individual cell.

same thing works for (for example) the `heightForRowAtIndexPath`: you just insert if-statements as stated above, and you can set the height for any individual cell.

Normally, if you need to setup the same thing for a bunch of cells, you would do it with an array, and populate the tableview with it, but if you really need specific settings for a specific cell, this is the easiest and best way (in my opinion)

hope this helps you all!

Comment: This is not a very good idea, because the more rows you have, the more  `if` statements you will need.

Comment: that is true, that's why I'm saying that this only works if you need to do individual set-up for individual cell. I could also use all kinds of arrays, but I think this is easier than creating a whole bunch of arrays

Answer (score 1):

The best way I found to manage per-cell information is to create a cell-info class, and have it represent the data. On this class, you can flag whether the cell is selectable, type, handler, etc.

Then, after dequeueing your cell, prepare it for display according to the cell-info backing object.

---

Example:

```
@interface MyCellInfo

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* detail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* image;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelectable) BOOL selectable;
@property (nonatomic) SEL handlingSelector;
...

@end

@implementation MyCellInfo @end
```

This defines an example cell-info class which holds some properties on each cell.
For ease of use, we will register a cell class in the table for an example identifier in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: @"ExampleIdentifier"];
```

Your table view data source:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return dataSource.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [dataSource[section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ExampleIdentifier"];

    MyCellInfo* cellInfo = dataSource[indexPath.section];

    if(cellInfo.image == nil)
    {
        //Show image
    }
    else
    {
        [cell.textLabel setText:cellInfo.title];
        [cell.detailTextLabel setText:cellInfo.detail];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Your table view delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyCellInfo* cellInfo = dataSource[indexPath.section];

    return cellInfo.height;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyCellInfo* cellInfo = dataSource[indexPath.section];

    return cellInfo.selectable;
}

- (NSIndexPath*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyCellInfo* cellInfo = dataSource[indexPath.section];

    return cellInfo.selectable ? indexPath : nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyCellInfo* cellInfo = dataSource[indexPath.section];

    [self performSelector:cellInfo.handlingSelector withObject:cellInfo];
}
```

All that remains is for you to create the data and represent each entry with a `MyCellInfo` object. I used an array of arrays type of db, where the top level array represents sections, while each inner array is the section's cells, each a `MyCellInfo` object.

Comment: the idea sounds great, But since I am a beginner, I don't know how to do this. do you have something like a tutorial or sample project to show how this is done? thank you anyway!

Comment: I will provide an example in a bit.

Comment: @Imaginedigital added example.

Comment: makes sense! thanks for the effort and time you took for this!

Answer (score 0):

The Apple Developer website has a page called "A Closer Look at UITableViewCell"

Located here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

The sections that you should focus on are:

**Managing Selections**
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH9-SW6